# Commit code to SVN failing: "folder exists with this name"

Tags: svn, commit

Recently I had done a successful commit to my SVN repository. But now I made some changes in code and also add some files. Now I want to re-commit this new folder(same name with previous commit) to SVN.

I tried to that by first replace my folder with new folder in my checkout directory. Then I run
`svn status` then `svn add shardha/`.

It is showing some error that there are already folder exist with this name at SVN.

Comment: Why is -1. I don't understand ?

Comment: probably because your understanding of SVN isn't very clear, and it shows in how you posed your 'question'.

Comment: Most likely because it is hard to understand what you have problems with and what you want to achieve. (not my -1 however).

Comment: I would suggest you to spend an hour or two reading the Subversion book on http://svnbook.red-bean.com/ .

Answer (score 5):

Why don't you just commit the changes?  Why do you need to make a new folder? Is it that you are getting conflicts and don't know how to resolve them? Did you make sure to update before you started working? I don't think a lot of you needed to do was necessary.

In order to make changes to a working copy, you should:

1. run svn update to make sure you are working against the HEAD, and that you're base revision matches that
2. make you're changes locally
3. run svn commit and work against the conflicts as they arise if necessary

The point with SVN is that it just tracks the differences in a filetree. That's why nothing is ever really deleted, and you can always revert back to a particular revision. Perhaps you are just not clear on the fundamentals/basics?

Comment: why would you remove the 'bullet' point formatting?  It loses it's effect that way.   nm: I realized the post came out that way, as originally intended.  sorry.

Comment: But what if i want to delete the whole folder then copy new one in it after that commit again.Sorry for poor english..but i have added a lot of files in it

Comment: why would you want to delete the folder if you are going to copy a new one in of the same name?  just delete the contents, commit the deletions, and then work in the folder again to add/edit whatever you want.  kind of seems pointless to commit files you are going to delete though...  what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Thanks, I understood but 
on my first commit my directory structure was look like this:
/amit/svn/web
/amit/svn/css
/amit/svn/index.html

Now i want to add three files into it and also want to delete css folder. Recently i commited and found that these three files are successfully added but what aout the css folder i want to remove from repository

Comment: waiting for your reply thescientist

Comment: this is why you probably got a downvote, because it it shows you aren't clear about how SVN works.  even the basics is enough to know that _nothing_ is ever deleted or removed from the repository.  it is just a history of changes over time.  you can 'remove' the css folder from showing up in the HEAD, but it will always be there.  you just need to delete it, commit the change, and then update.  from then on your working copy should not see it.  it will still exists in the repository though, just not in the latest revision.

Comment: I did that first i shift+delete that folder then commit ti shows error that this folder is missing.Then i run the command svn delete css.Nothing happen.....Please i am beginner i will read the tutorial but for the sake of god please help me this time

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, in your working copy you have a folder named shardha (let's call it foo) and you:

1. move foo to foo.bak
2. make a new directory named foo
3. then `svn add foo` (the new one) which fails

You need to:

1. `svn move foo foo.bak` or `svn delete foo`
2. then svn add your new foo and commit